# Quotient of a Hausdorff topological group by a closed subgroup 

Tags: gn.general-topology, gr.group-theory

Sorry if this question is below the level of this site: I've read that the quotient of a Hausdorff topological group by a closed subgroup is again Hausdorff. I've thought about it but can't seem to figure out why. Is it obvious? A simple yes or no (with reference is possible) is all I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Below I expand my crude original answer "[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space)"  as requested
by the community.

---

Yes. Let $G$ be the group and $H$ be the closed subgroup. The [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_of_a_function)  of the quotient map $G \to G/H$ 
is equal to $\Delta^{-1}(H)$ where  $\Delta : G \times G \to G$ 
is the continuous function $\Delta(x,y)= x- y$. Hence the kernel is closed. According
to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space#Properties) $G/H$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Given that the result is *false* without group structure, and given that your link is to the wiki article rather than a particular subsection, -1. Will upvote if you expand on this

Comment: I am not sure a question like this needs much more explanation. See the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9014/field-structure-for-rn

Comment: But then don't answer because this link is useless :)

Comment: Yes, the last line certainly implies G/H Hausd iff H closed. However, why is the last line true. (My apologies is this glaringly obvious.)

Comment: +1 (i.e. revert now we have expanded on this). As people have said, the key is that in a top group a weak separation axiom boosts up to an *a priori* stronger one.

Comment: I have no objection to a one-word wikipedia link.  A link to the proper subsection would be better, of course.

Comment: @Theo: my point was that the wikipedia page being linked to doesn't seem to discuss topological groups, and it is really the "homogeneity" (informally speaking) that a top grp structure imposes which makes the desired result work. Hence there is IMHO no subsection of that page which would help someone who didn't already know the method of proof - though if jvp can point out the intended section that would be great.

Comment: Re: the updated version - that's better, but I still think that there are a lot of extraneous bits in that section which might distract. Why not add a sentence just before your final one, saying "Hence the kernel is closed", and then the reader knows which bit of the wiki entry is being used. It's a nice argument, by the way.

Comment: I edited again. 

Answer (score 14):

In fact, an even stronger statement holds: If $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is an (abstract) subgroup, then $G/H$ is Hausdorff if and only if $H$ is closed (cf Bourbaki, General Topology, III.2.5, prop 13). It's not hard to prove.

Comment: Yes, before I posted the question I saw that H closed implies G/H T_0. What I couldn't see was that T_0 implies T_2 for a topological group. Is it obvious?