# When is a topological group Hausdorff (separated)?

Tags: topological-groups, reference-request

Does someone knows a good reference for the following result?

"A topological group is Hausdorff if and only if the identity is closed."

I have seen proofs in lecture notes of courses on the web, but I would like a reference in a book or an article, in order to refer to it.

Comment: I don't think this is the sort of fact you have to have a reference for in a paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find a routin proof in the book "Topological Ring" written by Seth Warner. In this book at page 21 in Theorem 3.4 you could see the following Proposition:

Theorem: Let $G$ be a topological group. The following statements are equivalent:

1. {$0$} is closed.
2. {$0$} is an intersection of the neighborhoods of zero.
3. $G$ is Hausdorff.
4. $G$ is regular.

---

You could also find the improvement of it in the book "**Topology for analysis**" Written by **Albert Wilansky**. In section 12 at page 243 You could see  the following theorem:

THEQREM: Every topological group is completely regular. The following conditions on 
a topological group $G$ are equivalent:

- $G$ is a $T_0$ space.
- $G$ is a Tychonoff space.-
- $\cap${$U:U$ is a is a neighborhood of $e$}={$e$}

The Proof of Complete regularity Has more details. I think The proof is in the level of Urysohn Lemma.

---

But if you are interested in the general case, I Suggest You look at the section "uniformity"  which were discussed in the following books:

- Topology for Analysis: Chapter 11
- General topology: Stephen Willard: chapter 9

Answer (score 4):

You can probably find this result in a million places, one of which is N. Bourbaki, *General Topology*, Part 1, Chapter 3, Section 1.2, p. 223, Proposition 2.

Answer (score 2):

Bourbaki, General Topology, III.2.5, prop 13. This is from an answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9022/quotient-of-a-hausdorff-topological-group-by-a-closed-subgroup).